# Has the hash password function changed in magento? If so, to what?

Tags: validation, magento, authentication, md5, saltedhash

I am using magento version 1.9.0.1.

For switching to magento purposes I need to create a login function for customers outside the magento framework.

I have looked up the method magento uses to hash and validate passwords, but the method doesn't seem to work anymore.

Below the code I use to validate a user login outside magento. This code is just to try proof of concept and is not being used in a live environment for obvious reasons :).

```
function checkPassword($entity,$passwordInput){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM customer_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id = '$entity' AND attribute_id = '12' LIMIT 1");
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    $fetch_data = explode(':',$fetch->value);
    $hashed_password = $fetch_data['0'];
    $salt = $fetch_data['1'];

    $hashInput = md5($passwordInput . $salt);
    if($hashInput == $hashed_password){
        return 'Success';
    }
    else{
        return 'Failure';
    }
}
```

`$entity` is the entity_id passed after email validation,

`$passwordInput` is the password entered in the login form.

It returns Failure. Which I'm not surprised about because when I return `$hashInput` and compare it with `$hashed_password` it's not the same.

Has the way Magento hashes passwords been changed? Or is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: Have you solved that issue? If so, can you send solution?

Comment: Yes, it has been a while back but the above code does actually work (only for customers). I made a stupid mistake and wrong data was being posted ($passwordInput wasn't right) Therefore it obviously returned Failure. Don't use this code in live environment though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check in `\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Customer.php` you can find something like this *(near line 430)* :

```
/**
 * Encrypt password
 *
 * @param   string $password
 * @return  string
 */
public function encryptPassword($password)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->encrypt($password);
}
```

The `helper('core')` is `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php`

In `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Data.php`, you find :

```
/**
 * Encrypt data using application key
 *
 * @param   string $data
 * @return  string
 */
public function encrypt($data)
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        return $data;
    }
    return $this->getEncryptor()->encrypt($data);
}
```

and `getEncryptor()` function is :

```
/**
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Encryption
 */
public function getEncryptor()
{
    if ($this->_encryptor === null) {
        $encryptionModel = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_ENCRYPTION_MODEL);
        if ($encryptionModel) {
            $this->_encryptor = new $encryptionModel;
        } else {
            $this->_encryptor = Mage::getModel('core/encryption');
        }

        $this->_encryptor->setHelper($this);
    }
    return $this->_encryptor;
}
```

`$this->_encryptor` is in `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Encryption.php` and in this file you can find :

```
/**
 * Encrypt a string
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return string
 */
public function encrypt($data)
{
    return base64_encode($this->_getCrypt()->encrypt((string)$data));
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Instantiate crypt model
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @return Varien_Crypt_Mcrypt
 */
protected function _getCrypt($key = null)
{
    if (!$this->_crypt) {
        if (null === $key) {
            $key = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/crypt/key');
        }
        $this->_crypt = Varien_Crypt::factory()->init($key);
    }
    return $this->_crypt;
}
```

`(string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/crypt/key');` is in `/app/etc/local.xml` file.

Your variable `$hashed_password` pass by this last method.

**Your variable `$hashInput` also pass there ?**

---

So, you can change in your `checkPassword()` function :

```
$hashInput = md5($passwordInput . $salt);
```

to

```
$hashInput = encryptPassword($passwordInput);
```

Thereby, `$hashInput` and `$hashed_password` will follow the same way.

Comment: My function needs to operate outside the magento framework. So it needs to function without the use of any magento classes/functions.

Comment: And if you try this : `$hashInput = md5($salt . $passwordInput);` // see:Mage_Core_Model_Encryption at line 74

Comment: Better late than never, thanks for your help. The end result was a stupid mistake on my side, wrong data was being posted and therefore it returned Failure. Thank you for giving me more insights on magento code though!